# Limit of a sequence ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let's assume that $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ fulfill the equation
$$
a_{n} + b_{n}\sqrt{3} = (2+\sqrt{3})^n, \hspace{0.5cm} n=1,2,\dots
$$
Compute the limit 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}.$$

Being honest, I do not know where to start and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try binomial theorem and sieve out terms with $\sqrt 3$

Comment: Are $a_n$ and $b_n$ rational?

Comment: There was no info in the exercise about that

Comment: Then there is something strange... because if $a_n=0$ and $b_n =\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n}{\sqrt{3}}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, and if $a_n=(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ and $b_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is undefined.

Comment: $a_n$ and $b_n$ are naturally natural numbers.

Comment: @choco_addicted I think the question means that when the Right hand side expression is expanded, and terms without $\sqrt 3$ are collected and summed, that is $a_n$, and sum of terms with a $\sqrt 3 $ is $b_n$

Comment: @Bernard How does one know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are restricted to natural numbers?

Comment: Use the binomial formula for $(2+\sqrt3)^n$.

Comment: Thats what I already said Bernard :) But I am a little unsure because it will not converge, which may/ maynot be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A start: Although this is not mentioned explicitly in the post, we assume that the $a_n$, $b_n$ are obtained by taking the natural expansion of $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$, and collecting terms that do not involve $\sqrt{3}$ together, and terms that involve $\sqrt{3}$ together. So for example if $n=2$, then $a_n=7$ and $b_n=4$.

Take the conjugates of both sides. We get
$$a_n-b_n\sqrt{3}=(2-\sqrt{3})^n.$$
Add and subtract to get explicit expressions for $a_n$ and $b_n$.

*Added:* If $x$ and $y$ are rational, the *conjugate* of $x+y\sqrt{3}$ is defined to be the number $x-y\sqrt{3}$. To show that $(2-\sqrt{3})^n=a_n-b_n\sqrt{3}$, show that if $s,t,u,v$ are rational then the conjugate of $(s+t\sqrt{3})(u+v\sqrt{3})$ is $(s-t\sqrt{3})(u-v\sqrt{3})$ (the conjugate of a product is the product of the conjugates). This is a computation.

Alternately, one can compare the binomial expansions of $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ and $(2-\sqrt{3})^n$.

**Remark:** We sketch another solution that connects the problem more explicitly with number theory. Note that 
$$(a_n+b_n\sqrt{3})(a_n-b_n\sqrt{3}=(2+\sqrt{3})^n(2-\sqrt{3})^n=1,$$
since $(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=1$.

It follows that $a_n^2-3b_n^2=1$. So the $a_n$, $b_n$ are integer solutions of the Pell equation $x^2-3y^2=1$. It is clear that the $a_n$ and $b_n$ $\to\infty$. But for large $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2-3y^2=1$, we have $x^2\approx 3y^2$, so $\frac{x}{y}\approx \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: What assures the equality of the conjugates?

Comment: @DrMV: I left out that part. The simplest way of doing it is to show that if $s,t,u,v$ are integers, or indeed rationals, then the conjugate of $(s+t\sqrt{3})(u+v\sqrt{3})$ is $(s-\sqrt{3})(u-\sqrt{3})$. This is a straightforward computation. Alternately, use the binomial theorem.

Comment: And how does one know that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are not generally real numbers and not restricted to be integers or rational numbers?  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV because the coefficients of $1$ ($a_n$) and of $\sqrt{3}$ ($b_n$) in the expansion of $(2\pm \sqrt{3})^n$ are all integers.

Comment: @Dr.MV:  Again, either note that the product $(s+\sqrt{3})(u+v\sqrt{3})$, where $s,t,u,v$ are integers, has shape $x+y\sqrt{3}$ where $x$ and $y$ are explicitly computable integers, or use the binomial theorem.

Comment: @Larara For $n=1$, we have $a_1+\sqrt{3}b_1=2+\sqrt{3}$.  That does not imply that $a_1=2$ and $b_1=1$.   That is only $1$ possibility.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That presumes that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers.  That is certainly not stated.  For $n=1$, we have $a_1+\sqrt 3 b_1=2+\sqrt 3$.  But that only gives one equation for the two real numbers $a_1$ and $b_1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV that's the only possibility if we think of the set $\{a+b\sqrt{3}\,|\,a,\,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Examples for more details.

Comment: @Larara And why should we think that?  There is nothing in the problem statement that suggests any restrictions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Dr.MV I think that maybe this is implicit in the question, otherwise, for each $n$ we would have infinity possibilities for $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: @Larara Yes, that is my point.

Comment: @Dr.MV: It is true that nothing was mentioned explicitly in the OP about how the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are determined. But the default assumption is that they are obtained from the "natural" expansion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It is obviously a quite reasonable assumption - just though that one should consider stating this up front.  ;-)) -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: As you suggested, I made the assumption explicit, and at the very front.

Comment: @AndréNicolas +1 for the solid answer. -Mark